# In a YouTrack issue how to enable only the assignee to change the State of the issues

Tags: youtrack

As a Developer I do not want accidentally update the State of someone else's issue by drag and dropping it on the agile board.

Or more generally, if an issue is assigned to a developer we do not want to enable other developers (only managers) to change the fields of the issue.

The update of Private Fields can be disabled at Roles level. Is it possible to enable the update of some Private Fields for the Assignee only even if it is disabled at Roles level? It could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in functionality for such case, but you can use a custom workflow for this: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/Workflow+Guide

Comment: I was afraid that there was no better (more simple) solution.